# Issues in android studio downloading

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, opera, mozilla

I am trying to download Android studio but the problem is after visiting developer site and accepting the terms I proceed to click download.

Then the strange thing is after clicking download button the site immediately redirects to installing procedure but the android studio setup file doesn't get side load into download bar of chrome.

I even tried it on mozilla,opera browers but its not getting download plss help someone provide me alternative direct link...

Comment: Did you download it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Here I am giving Download links for Android Studio

Windows (64-bit) + Android SDK -- [Click Here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.3.1.0/android-studio-bundle-162.3871768-windows.exe)

Windows (64-bit) No Android SDK -- [Click Here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.3.1.0/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-windows.exe)

Windows (64-bit) No Android SDK, No Installer -- [Click Here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.3.1.0/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-windows.zip)

Windows (32-bit) No Android SDK, No Installer -- [Click Here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.3.1.0/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-windows32.zip)

Mac -- [Click Here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.3.1.0/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-mac.dmg)

Linux -- [Click Here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.3.1.0/android-studio-ide-162.3871768-linux.zip)