# The Android Studio download link is broken. How can I download Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I go to the [Official Android Studio Download page](https://developer.android.com/studio) and click on download, I get this:

> It looks like the webpage at
> https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/2023.2.1.23/android-studio-2023.2.1.23-windows.exe
> might be having issues, or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

I use Edge but I also tried on Chrome and Vivaldi to no avail.

I found [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832793/issues-in-android-studio-downloading) but it's rather outdated.

Comment: For Windows, try Chocolatey (https://chocolatey.org/).  For Mac, use Brew (https://brew.sh/).

Comment: I'm getting a similar error now:  
 > ```The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/2023.2.1.23/android-studio-2023.2.1.23-windows.exe'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote name could not be resolved: 'redirector.gvt1.com'"
The install of androidstudio was NOT successful.``` (Sorry for the terrible formatting. I'm not used to markdown :P)

Comment: Just checked and it worked for me

Comment: That's weird... It could be that I'm trying to access this at my school. I'm not sure. I wish I had mobile data to test that theory out.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski What command did you use? I used ```choco install androidstudio```.

Comment: No command. Just clicked download link

Comment: May be your school network is blocking certain domains?

Comment: Hey. Sorry for waiting so long to respond. I'm at home now and the link still isn't working.